# Django test: Setting cookie (Django 1.11+)

Tags: django, session, testing

I have troubles setting cookie in Django test.

```
class Test_views(TestCase):

    def test_set_cookie(self):
        session = self.client.session
        session['mycookie'] = 'testcookie'
        session.save()
        response = self.client.get(reverse('homepage')) 
        ...
```

I print the cookies in the Views to be sure:

views.py

```
... 
def homepage(request):
        print(request.session.keys())
        ...
```

And indeed, the cookie `mycookie` doesn't exist.

Apparently, that's the right way to set cookie:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session

**By the way, using request.factory, it's working:**

```
def add_session_to_request( request):
    """Annotate a request object with a session (RequestFactory doesn't permit Session"""
    middleware = SessionMiddleware()
    middleware.process_request(request)
    request.session.save()


class Test_views(TestCase): # testing with cookies set

    def setUp(self):
        super(Setting_cookie, self).setUp()
        factory = RequestFactory()
        self.request = factory.get(reverse('homepage'))
        add_session_to_request(self.request)

     def test_set_cookie(self):
        session = self.request.session
        session['mycookie'] = 'testcookie'
        session.save()
        response = homepage(self.request) 
        ...
```

Comment: Can't reproduce; this works fine for me. Although note there is nothing here to do with cookies at all, session data is not usually stored in cookies. And the TestCase class already has a `client` attribute, which you should use rather than creating your own in `setUpClass`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea how I debug this then since it's working for you and not with my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong SESSION_ENGINE in settings:

`SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'`

I forgot that I've done that...

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same problem. What do you mean by wrong SESSION_ENGINE ?

Comment: the SESSION_ENGINE used inside the test is the default one: it's a database-backed sessions ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine ). If you use a non-default one, like a cookie-based sessions (which is what I've done by defining SESION_ENGINE), the test couldn't use sessions anymore. So, to be short, leave it default! But it may not be this same error for you even if if the symptoms look the same.